# Recognize '§' with php

Tags: php, string, escaping, explode

i have a string and i want to convert them into an array using the character '§' :

```
<?php
$string="element1§element2§element3";
$array=explode("&sect;",$string); //tried also &#167; and §,double and single quotes
print_r($array);
?>
```

The output is always this :

```
Array ( [0] =>element1§element2§element3)
```

How can i let php recognize the '§' symbol in order to split the string into an array?

EDIT :
I get the string from a file using file() function and iterating the array through a foreach. If i use my own example it works, but with the exernal file do not.

The rowurlencode() of my string is the follow:

`element1%A7element2%A7element3`

Comment: Why are you using the literal character in line 2, but the ampersand-encoded version in line 3? Stick to one format.

Comment: I have tried exactly your code with §, and got: `Array ( [0] => element1 [1] => element2 [2] => element3 ) ` ; here it is: <?php
$string="element1§element2§element3";
$array=explode("§",$string); 
print_r($array);
?>

Comment: already tried, the "$string" is just an example, i get it already formatted like that from another source, but both escaped chars and literal character do not solve question

Comment: that's why you should always ask **a real question**. what's the point in asking with an "example" string which obviously works? You should provide **a real** string you have a problem with

Comment: You're right, i didn't think it should be so relevant, my bad.

Comment: rawurlencode() your *actual* string and add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rawurlencode your string to see the **actual** code of this character.

then use this code as a delimiter

```
$array=explode("\xA7",$string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Works perfectly for me

```
ini_set('default.charset', 'UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF8');

$string="element1§element2§element3";
$array=explode("§",$string);

print_r($array); //Array ( [0] => element1 [1] => element2 [2] => element3 )
```

Comment: if i set ini_set() and header() it don't get anymore "§" but replace it with "�"
I get the string from a file using file() function and iterating the array through a foreach. If i use my own example it works, but with the exernal file do not

Comment: I had exactly the same issue as yours. So if you want to load data from external file, you need to ensure that file is in `UTF-8 without BOM`. For example, *Notepad++* does it. The problem is encoding..

Answer (score 0):

If you literally used:

```
<?php
  $string="element1§element2§element3";
  $array=explode("§",$string);
  print_r($array);
?>
```

This will work. My guess is that in your case `$string` comes from a different source, and is not in the same character encoding as your PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer, thanks to Your Common Sense.
Simply, i change my explode() function like this :

```
$array=explode("%A7",rawurlencode($string));
```

Where "%A7" is the rawurlencode of "§".